# Timing recursive functions and general being stuck-ness

Tags: javascript

I am working on a project to create an energy cost/savings calculator for a client. I have been writing it in pure JavaScript so far, but am more than happy to use jQuery where necessary. I'm still starting out learning the language, so I apologize in advance for any bad practices, egregious errors, or simple mistakes.

There are two requirements:

1. The user can input their energy use information, and see how much they will save by using the client's product (I just have the input so far, am planning to use those returned values to output the savings later)
2. The numbers animate in some way when they are presented.

For the animation, I'm just going with the number counting up or down from its current position. My problem is I'm absolutely stuck with how to achieve this. I'm told that I want to use a timer on a recursive function that either increments or decrements the displayed number based upon the old value versus the newly input value.

So when the user selects a number, the display will count up to that number from zero with a space of, say, ~300ms between each change. And if they select a different number, it will count up or down.

[Here is a link to the live page.](http://justinwestphal.com/test/calculator/calculator.html) For some reason the selected number doesn't show up in the DOM in the jsfiddle version. [Here is the .js file.](http://justinwestphal.com/test/calculator/js/script.js)

I would very much appreciate any help to nudge me out of my little rut. As I said, I'm still in the baby stages of learning JavaScript, so I can't quite think fluidly in the language yet. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird, it is for me now as well. Better to go to the live site. The script is in /js/script.js . Sorry about that, I haven't used fiddle before, I probably needed to create an account to save it!

Answer (score 1):

this may be enough to get you started:

http://jsfiddle.net/pLJU6/

```
var number = 0;
var div = $('#numberDiv');

var incrementNumber = function () {
    div.text(number);
    number++;
    setTimeout(incrementNumber, 300);
};

incrementNumber();
```

Comment: It almost did. The function needs to be independent for each section. I need to be able to target that section's little output box only, and count up or down in it. I've been using innerHTML so I can stick the var directly in the <h2> tags... would you mind taking a peek at the live version and letting me know what you think? I'm sorry I keep getting stuck on this :(

Comment: @DesignUtensil store your numbers in an array, then pass the element and number being incremented into the function.